# converting data to struct hostent from getaddrinfo()

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, posix

I am replacing old code to linux. I was using:

```
server_host = getipnodebyname(host.c_str(), AF_INET, 0, &err_num);
```

and

```
server_host = getipnodebyaddr(addr, sizeof(INET_ADDRSTRLEN), AF_INET, &err_num);
```

that it has to be replaced by the new getaddrinfo().

At moment I added:

```
struct addrinfo *p_addr = (struct addrinfo *) NULL;
struct addrinfo hints={0};                                          //Initialize the addrinfo hints
char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]={0};
int result = 0;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;                                          //Request for IPV4 ADDRESSES ONLY

result = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &p_addr);
```

but I need to populate the gathered information in the hostent structure:

```
hostent     *server_host;
```

for compatibility with other code.
I could use the gethostbyname() to get directly the hostent structure but I want avoid it.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no C library function to convert an `addrinfo` into a `hostent`.  You will have to construct the `hostent` yourself using the data from the `addrinfo`, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;

addrinfo *p_addrs = NULL;

int result = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &p_addrs);
if (result != 0) ... // error handling...

std::vector<in_addr*> in_addrs;

for(addrinfo *p_addr = p_addrs; p_addr != NULL; p_addr = p_addr->ai_next) {
    in_addrs.push_back(&reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(p_addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr);
}
in_addrs.push_back(NULL);

hostent hst;
h.h_name = p_addrs->ai_canonname;
h.h_aliases = NULL;
h.h_addrtype = AF_INET;
h.h_length = sizeof(in_addr);
h.h_addr_list = reinterpret_cast<char**>(&in_addrs[0]/* or: in_addrs.data() */);

// use hst as needed ...

freeaddrinfo(p_addrs);
```